# SharePoint query suggestions not working and I'm not an overall search admin

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

Hi universe :)  I am a site collection admin and I really want the search query suggestions functionality to work on my site.  When searching for help, I see a lot of responses that would work if I had greater permissions.  Is there a way I can do it as a collections admin without having to make changes to the entire enterprise search center (as I don't have that ability).  Responses appreciated!!!

Comment: @Erin...you need to be farm admin to create query suggestions..Query suggestions are set under Search Service Application administration....as site collection admin you cannot do it..

Comment: If I've seen search suggestions populate before, does it just mean there's some rule behind the scenes whereby a search term or query has to be executed some number of times before it will populate as a suggestion?  @SiddharthVaghasia   (Thank you for your response!!!)

Comment: @Erin..have added your query as answer....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query suggestion can be added manually but Sharepoint also creates it automatically.....

The search system automatically creates suggestions for a query when users have clicked one or more of the results for that query at least six times. The query suggestions are generated daily for each result source and for each site collection, so the automatic query suggestions can be different for different result sources and site collections.

**For Manually** adding phrase to query suggestion, below steps can be followed

To add phrases that you want the search system to always or never suggest to users as they start typing a query, you have to create one or several text files that contain these phrases, and then import the files into the search system.

To add phrases that should always be used as query suggestions

Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.

Open the Query Suggestion Settings page.

On the home page of the SharePoint Central Administration website, in the 
Application Management section, click Manage service applications.

On the Manage Service Applications page, click the Search service application.

On the Search Administration Page, in the Queries and Results section, click Query Suggestions. The Query Suggestion Settings page opens.

In the Language for suggestion phrases section, select the processing language for the query suggestions that you always want to suggest.

In the Always suggest phrases section, click Import from text file.

Browse to the file that you want to import and click OK.

Click Save Settings.

[Ref link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj721441.aspx)